# Is it possible to bind a parent component’s property, via template, to a child component computed property?

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to bind a parent component's property, via template, to a child component computed property?

The goal is to access the child component's computed property via binding.

```
// We are in some parent component's template
{{child-component aComputedProp=aNonComputedProp}}
```

---

```
// Parent component
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  aNonComputedProp: null
});
```

---

```
// Child component
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  aComputedProp: function () {
    return 4 + 4;
  }.property()
});
```

**UPDATE**

@KalmanKalman Hazins

Although this approach works well when an action is performed on that child component, it won't work when an *ancestor component* needs to access data from that child component.

Here's an image that describes the dilemma.

[image]

The only way I can think of having components communicate with each other, without having hard dependencies, is through a service (or the parent component acting as a service), and a series of trigger/handler events that are APIs in disguise.

**UPDATE**

An alternative method I was thinking was decorating the parent controller from ChildComponent1 via:

```
  decorateTargetObject: function () {
    Ember.defineProperty(this.get('targetObject'), 'height', Ember.computed(function () {
      return this.$().outerHeight();
    }.bind(this)));
  }.on('init')
```

And ChildComponent2 could access that property via `this.get('targetObject.height')`

Granted this breaks one-way encapsulation since the component needs to dip into its controller.

Is there not a way to set an existing property to a computed property without redefining it (without `Ember.defineProperty`)?

```
//In ChildComponent1
decorateTargetObject: function () {
  this.set('targetObject.height', ...a computed function...)
}.on('init')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (directly via template), but this is how you would do it :) (instead).

You can send an action to the parent and pass it the value to change. Then, inside the parent action, you can update the value.

```
App.XParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  helloParent: null,

  actions: {
    updateHelloParent: function(value){
      this.set('helloParent', value);
    }
  }
});

App.XChildComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  helloName: function(){
    var name = this.get('name');
    var helloName = '';
    if(name) {
      var helloName = "Hello " + name;
    }

    this.sendAction('action', helloName);

    return helloName;      
  }.property('name')
});
```

Your templates would look as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-parent">
  <h2>Parent</h2>

  {{ helloParent }}

  {{ x-child action="updateHelloParent"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-child">
  <h2>Child</h2>

  {{ input value=name }} <p/> 

  {{ helloName }}
</script>
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuceja/1/edit?html,js,output)

**UPDATE**

Based on the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_lightweight-services-with-code-needs-code), you can do the following for your use-case:

```
App.HeightController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  height: 0
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['height'],
  height: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.height.height')
});

App.XChild1Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  heightDidChange: function(){
    var val = this.get('val');
    if(val) {
      this.set('height', parseInt(val));  
    }    
  }.observes('val')
});
```

Then, in your templates, you can have the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  Height(index): {{ height }} <p/>
  {{ x-parent height=height}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-parent">
  <h2>Parent</h2>

  Height(parent): {{ height }} <p/>

  {{ x-child1 height=height}}

  {{ x-child2 height=height}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-child1">
  <h2>Child 1</h2>

  Height(child1): {{ height }} <p/>
  {{ input value=val placeholder='Type new heght here...'}} <p/> 

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/x-child2">
  <h2>Child 2</h2>

  Height(child2): {{ height }} <p/>    
</script>
```

Updated solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuceja/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: 2 issues with this method: [1] What if the property cannot be observed, such as a jQuery `outerWidth` method, hence it needs to be a computed property. [2] Since the component is using `observes`, the observed property needs to fire a change event, what if it never changes?